# Runtime error 3134 in visual basic

Tags: vba, ms-access

`CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO Customer(FirstName, LastName, E-mail, Password, PhoneNumber, Address, City, State, Zipcode) " & " VALUES('" & Me.FirstName & "','" & Me.LastName & "','" & Me.E_mail & "','" & Me.Password & "', " & Me.PhoneNumber & ",'" & Me.Address & "','" & Me.City & "', '" & Me.ZipCode & "')"`

I am new to visual basic and access, trying to insert a row on button click in access, could not figure out the syntax error in this visual basic code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Drop " & " you put in front of VALUES.

Comment: Although I am not 100% sure what your end goal is here. It looks like you may have just added your "VALUES" fields in the wrong place. It probably should look something like `CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO Customer '" & Me.FirstName & "' AS FirstName,'" & Me.LastName & "' AS LastName,'" ...` etc.

Comment: Would also need to drop the `"` on either side of the `&`, in that case, @Rene. It's extraneous, but not causing an error.

Answer (score 3):

Password is a reserved word, so use: [Password]

Comment: needed in both the column list and `me.Password`, I believe.

Comment: No - that's fine, though I would prefer `Me!Password.Value`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I see another issue now. MS Access does not accept E-mail as a column name. Use [E-mail]. Assuming there are no other issues, that will likely solve the problem.

Edit:

As a futher explanation, this is because of the '-' (dash) in E-mail. The same would apply for any column that starts with a number (such as "1234Column").

Answer (score 1):

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO Customer(FirstName, LastName, E-mail, Password, PhoneNumber, Address, City, State, Zipcode) VALUES('" & Me.FirstName & "','" & Me.LastName & "','" & Me.E_mail & "','" & Me.Password & "', " & Me.PhoneNumber & ",'" & Me.Address & "','" & Me.City & "', '" & Me.ZipCode & "')"
```